# How to put a Listbox item at the bottom of relative panel in windows store app

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, listbox

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBoxItem Name="Home">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="36"  Text="&#xE80F;" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="24" Margin="20,0,0,0">Home</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

When I'm using the following code. I'm able to get the `listboxitem` at the top of the relative panel and not at the bottom. How to do that.